# assign an interval (mathematic) to a js variable

Tags: javascript, variables, increment, intervals

Can the value of a Java variable be an interval (mathematic)? 
and if yes how to assign it?

In other words, in math on a piece of paper I would explain it this way:

- y = f(x) = c  with y being a natural number (of this kind
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) and
- x being an interval (of this kind
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

Practically:

- I don't mind the f(x) which might be super complicated mathematically,
- I want to asign the value c to the variable y when the value of
  the variable x is [a-b]

So for instance:

- if x = [1-2] then y = c === 1
- if x = [3-5] then y = c === 2
- if x = ]5-8] then y = c === 3
- and so on

Here is my try

I thought of *switch*, but I failed to use intervals,

I tried to use if

```
  var x;
  var y = 0;
  if (x >=1 && x <= 2 ){y++}
  if (x >=3 && x <= 5 ){y++}
```

But I bumped in the problem that

- y will always be equal to 0 or 1 if I define it inside of my function
- or y will always be equal to >1 and never revert to 1 if I define it outside of my function even if the value of x goes up to 4 and revert to 2

so I tried with *for*,

```
var x;
var y = 0;
for (x >=1 && x <= 3 ){y++}
for (x >=2 && x <= 5 ){y++}
```

but I bumped in a similar problem

So how to auto increment y at/for every interval in order that c will be equal to 1, 2, 3,etc. but also in order for c to be able to  revert to 1 if x revert to [1-3]

Finally I could use the value of x in for instance:

```
document.mydiv.innerHTML = '<img src="image' + x + '.jpg">'
```

and display one specific image for a given interval of value of x, that could be the time elapsed on a video for instance

Cheers

PS: this question is kind of the mathematical side of a practical wish described in the like below, I hope this second question does not appear as spam, but another approach that might be helpful by it's own and answer a question related to video that might interest others
 [function increment sync with video (or auto increment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966189/function-increment-sync-with-video-or-auto-increment)

Comment: First, are you talking about Java or Javascript ? Looks like Javascript from the snippet but you mention Java..

Comment: Note that you can simply type `y++;` and it will increment `y`. No need to do `y = y++;`

Comment: yes javascript, my bad

Comment: I know y++ is return the same result as y = y ++ but I phrase it this way in the post because I thought I would be more easily understood

Comment: Probably check if `x` is the right value by `alert`ing it or `console.log`ging it before making an element with it.

Comment: actually, x, is not really x, but the value displayed next to statut below the player in the link below, and I can get it by using "data.second"  http://codepen.io/bdougherty/pen/JgDfm. In fact I manage to get the right image at the right time, but since I have to display almost 2000 picts, I thought it would be best if I can automate the increment of y, imagine i have to add a pict in the midle of my serie i have to change half of them