# Multipage pdf - display specific page in html or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I've seen there are few options to display a pdf file within an HTML page

cf.(among others) [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Ok, what about if my pdf is multipage and I want to display a specific page ?
**And only a specific page** as if it was an image, meaning that the user can't scroll within the pdf.

Q) can I, and how to display a given page of a given pdf ?

imagine a kind of slide-show system, the aim would be to display within a `<div>`  a given page of a given pdf according to the user's demand.

**EDIT**

ok I've been re-thinking this and actually my question should have been

How can I do exactly like in the previous/next exemple (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/prevnext.html) if my project is hosted on a shared server on which I can't have an ssh access, install any packages or add librarie etc.

many thank's

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely my personal opinion and it's your choice whether to use this way or not, but I would recommend having an `iframe` with the `src` set to the required PDF document. Then, add some HTML `input` buttons with their `onclick` attribute set to change the source of the `iframe` to include the parameter for the page number (`#page=3`). As an example of what I mean, take a look at the code sample below:

```html
<iframe id="example" src="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf"></iframe>
<input value="Page 5" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('example').src='http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5';" />
<input value="Page 1" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('example').src='http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf';" />
```

Comment: Hi, that's a solution indeed, but I'm more loking for something like this http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/prevnext.html in term of functionality, with the exception that the user won't get button but the page will change according to the value of a js variable colected elsewhere

Comment: Hi, thank's for your porposal, actually I've forgottent to precise in my post that I wanted to have one page displayed, as if it was an image, so the use of pdfjs is better suited for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach is to use the PDF.JS library. It's a pure HTML5/JavaScript renderer for PDF documents without any third-party plugins.

Online demo: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

This is probably the best way to do it with JavaScript/HTML5

(Access specific page)
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#page=13

Comment: Thank's for this answer, but  I may have miss-formulated my question. Actually I would like to display a specific page, and only this page, I don't want the user to be able to scroll the pdf, as if each page were an image.

Comment: See other examples e.g. at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html

Comment: hi, thank's for your replies, indeed pdfjs is probably the way to go ! and the "hello word" or the "previous-next" exemple are ont top.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding [this example](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/prevnext.html),
I think that you should use the "View Source" feature in whichever browser you're using to get the HTML and JS for it, then add a JavaScript timer to trigger the `onPrevPage();` and `onNextPage();` JS functions.
If you need help creating a JS timer using the `setInterval` function to change the `pageNum` variable, see the following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: If you have some trouble with this, you may want to consider using BootStrap's carousel slideshow system. Please reply if you'd like me to provide some more information on this.

Comment: Hi, indeed I'll use a js to trigger the onPrevPage() function, however the setInterval won't do the job for me as I want the slides to change according to the value of a js varialble that contain the elapsed time video that I get through the vimeo api. actually I'm still stuck with this point see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966189/function-increment-sync-with-video-or-auto-increment and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995013/assign-an-interval-mathematic-to-a-js-variable, but it's an another story I'll address later

Comment: for bootstraps, the carousel look's nice, I'll have a closer look, but I may do the same within hype so will see

Comment: @Nathangrad 
Hi. Can you tell me something more about how to use carousel or adding a timer in my situation.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/54436219/5748603