# pdf.js jump to page programatically using vimeo.js variable

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, vimeo-api

I've been using the prevnext.html example provided with pdf.js to display pdf within my page as it almost perfectly fits my needs

now I would like to be abble to jump to a given page so I created a function base on the previous and next function

```
function onNextPage() {
    if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
```

here is my function as a simplified version of the `onNextPage` function of the example

```
function onMyPage(pageNum) {
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
```

that I call from a button like this

```
<button onclick="return onMyPage(10)">Mypage</button>
```

This is working fine.

on the same page I'm using vimeo.js to control my player and use event listnener
notabbly to know the elapsed time

```
player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
    if (data.seconds >= 0){imgNum = "1";}
    if (data.seconds >= 2.5){imgNum = "2";}
    if (data.seconds >= 18){imgNum = "3";}
    if (data.seconds >= 37.5){imgNum = "4";}
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = imgNum;           
});
```

this, for instance, enables me to display the value of `imgNum` in my `div id="output"`

**great**

**here starts the surprising things :** 
if I add my function `onMyPage` in the promise of my event listener, it only works with a number not a variable; see code below

```
player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
    if (data.seconds >= 0){imgNum = "1";}
    if (data.seconds >= 2.5){imgNum = "2";}
    if (data.seconds >= 18){imgNum = "3";}
    if (data.seconds >= 37.5){imgNum = "4";}

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = imgNum;
    onMyPage(11)
});
```

with the previous code, it indeed jump to the page 11 when the vimeo player is playing

```
player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
    if (data.seconds >= 0){imgNum = "1";}
    if (data.seconds >= 2.5){imgNum = "2";}
    if (data.seconds >= 18){imgNum = "3";}
    if (data.seconds >= 37.5){imgNum = "4";}

    pageNum = imgNum        
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = imgNum;
    document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = pageNum;

    onMyPage(pageNum)
});
```

but not with this one, while I'm sure that pageNum contains the right value thank's to my `div id="output2"`

and on top of that the previous and next button natively present in the prevnext.html example do not wokr properly when the player is playing, but without any fuss when the player is stopped (which is kind of normal)

seeing this I spend hours trying to make it work in tons of ways, but it never happend...
any help would be welcome
thank's in advance

Comment: First make pageNum as a number (e.g. via `+pageNum`). Second make sure you are not calling queueRenderPage on every 'timeupdate' -- in onMyPage compare pageNum with some cached global (e.g. 'myCurrentPageNum`) variable and if not equal update it and only call queueRenderPage then.

Comment: @async5 : thank's man, you're my king, you made my day, first you made me realise that my `imgNum` var was a string ( i was so ocussed on pdf.js that i was blind), nd then you gave me the trick to avoid to call `queueRenderPage` on every `timeupdate`. My last wish is related to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966189/function-increment-sync-with-video-or-auto-increment] the idea being to lighten my code where i have a succession of if and to simplify the writing of my intervals to something le this `[a, b, c, d, e, etc.]` in order to import it from an xml file.